# Vb Open a .Exe file in a panel?

Tags: vb.net

So here is my question? How do I open a .exe File in a panel?
What I am using: Visual Studio.
My problem: It is opening the .exe file out side of my form and not placing it in the panel.
Code:

```
Public Class Form1
Declare Auto Function SetParent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As Integer
Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
Private Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = 274
Private Const SC_MAXIMIZE As Integer = 61488
Dim proc As Process

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    proc = Process.Start("C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe")
    proc.WaitForInputIdle()

    SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, Panel1.Handle)
    SendMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Generally speaking, you can't run another windowed application inside your window.  What is it that you're trying to achieve?  If you explain the real problem you're trying to solve, perhaps we could help you find a solution.

Comment: Alright So what I really wanna do is run a .Exe file inside my form and the .exe file Is a Cnc simulator. The reason I want to run this in my form is because I want to make a play button for this program. At the moment to run the program you have to hit Page up to move it in steps. What i am going to do is make a auto clicker to hit page up like 1 click every 1 sec. Something along those lines. But I just need the program to run in a Panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the additional information provided, I suggest a different design.  You are better off building your own application that has a button, and when you press the button, you send a keystroke to the cnc application.  You can position your application next to the cnc application for your convenience.

It is extremely difficult to force another application to run inside your application, and even if you can get it to work, it is likely to be fragile.  Keep the two applications separate.  `SetParent` is not the solution.

I suggest that you take a look at [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), a (free) programming toolkit that people have used to automate all sorts of things.  Among other things, AutoHotKey is very good at simulating keystrokes for other applications (it is more complicated that simply using PostMessage/SendMessage).

For positioning windows, you should be able to write some code that automatically positions your window next to the cnc application, and you can even track movement of the cnc application and move your window correspondingly (this can get a bit tricky if you want to handle all the special cases such as moving your application to a different edge if there is not enough room).

Answer (score 0):

Pinvoke [SetParent](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setparent) is how to do it, but you may not get the exact behavior you want with some apps, and not all app will load with this API.